# TFS 2010 - Create a new project from an existing one in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch, team-project

I need to create a new project from an existing one in TFS. This is for source control only. I do not need to copy any work items.

so now i need to create NewTeamProject in NewProjectCollection and use the source branch of OldTeamProject in OldProjectCollection.

Kindly advise to go ahead with this.. Thanks a lot for your help in advance..

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Split**

- Create a new team project in your existing collection
- Pick the branch from team project option in the creation wizard
- [Follow the split a team project collection guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936158%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Delete)

However, I have a feeling that this will not bring all the history along with it, and it's not a particularly nice option, especially when it comes to the collection splitting.

**TFS Integration Tools**

Another way is to use the tfs integration platform, which basically replays all the checkins on a new team project, which can be in your new collection.  You will lose the original date/time of the checkin, due to the way this program works but will still be able to see what each checkin changed.

[TFS Integration Tools](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)
[Tfs integration tools blog posts and references](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/06/06/toc-tfs-integration-tools-blog-posts-and-reference-sites.aspx)

There is one risky way to get your timestamps correct, by [manually updating the database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsintegration/thread/7459e196-8f34-4b2e-a99e-4598328c9833)

Comment: If I want to create a copy of the source control for a team project in to an another team project in the same collection and the same server?

Comment: The do the first one, but don't bother with the team project collection splitting.